# Pass current user in ASP.NET MVC controller to DAL

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using windows authentication for my ASP.NET application. Fetching the current user name is fairly straightforward in razor views i.e `@User.Identity.Name`

The feature I am implementing is that I pass the current user name in my sql select query and get the associated role from the table. Next, I would like to pass the role back to the controller so that I can access it in all of my application views.

So that I could perform operations in my views like

```
@if (CurrentUserRole = "Admin") {
  // Do something
} else {
  // So something else
}
```

HomeController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using nmvs_db.dal;
using nmvs_module;
using nmvs_module.util;
using SecureMedi.Models;
using SecureMedi.DAL;

namespace SecureMedi.Controllers {
    public class HomeController: Controller {
        static HomeController() {
            foreach(string s in new string[] {
                "com.ibm.oauth.OAuthUtils",
                "nmvs_server",
                "nmvs_module"
            }) {
                var l = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(s);
                l.addAppender(new DotNetAppender());
                l.debug(s + " test");
            }
        }

        public IActionResult Error() {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Index() {
            ViewData["TextAreaResult"] = "No result yet";
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult AnotherPage() {
            ViewData["TextAreaResult"] = "No result yet";
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

UsersDAL.cs (DAL)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using SecureMedi.Models;

namespace SecureMedi.DAL {
    public class UsersDAL {
        public void CurrentUser(string currentUserName) {
            string connectionstring = "MY_CONNECTION_STRING";
            string sql = String.Format("select users.name 'Username', roles.name 'Role' from sys.database_principals users inner join sys.database_role_members memberof on users.principal_id = memberof.member_principal_id inner join sys.database_principals roles ON memberof.role_principal_id = roles.principal_id and roles.type = 'R' where users.name = '[{0}]'", currentUserName);
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (rdr.Read()) {
                string CurrentUserRole = rdr["Role"].ToString();
                rdr.Close();
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Running a query against DB table directly returns something like

Query

```
select users.name 'Username', roles.name 'Role' from sys.database_principals users inner join sys.database_role_members memberof on users.principal_id = memberof.member_principal_id inner join sys.database_principals roles ON memberof.role_principal_id = roles.principal_id and roles.type = 'R' where users.name = 'Domain\username'
```

Result

```
Username             Role 
Domain\username      Admin
```

Also, I am not 100% sure if I am passing the `currentUserName` arg correctly in my `CurrentUser` function.

I have looked up on
[How to get the current user in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263486/how-to-get-the-current-user-in-asp-net-mvc) and [How to pass a value from ASP.NET MVC controller to ASP.NET webforms control inside MVC View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527123/how-to-pass-a-value-from-asp-net-mvc-controller-to-asp-net-webforms-control-insi) but I am not sure how to pass the value of current user name to and fro from my controller and DAL.

Comment: make your CurrentUser method return a string, and writing `return CurrentUserRole;` would seem to be an obvious starting point? Then you can call that method, passing in User.Identity.Name as the current username, and fetch the current role back. As for passing the currentUserName arg into the database, it's not ideal because it's vulnerable to SQL injections. Take an ADO.NET tutorial and find out how to use parameters. See http://bobby-tables.com/ if you like, it has an explanation and some examples.

Comment: Your CurrentUser function returns nothing, and you declare local variable "CurrentUserRole" in if statement, how it should work? Also this method isn't static so you would have to create instance of UsersDAL class first to call it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public CurrentUser GetCurrentUser(string currentUserName) {
        string connectionstring = "MY_CONNECTION_STRING";
        string sql = String.Format("select users.name 'Username', roles.name 'Role' from sys.database_principals users inner join sys.database_role_members memberof on users.principal_id = memberof.member_principal_id inner join sys.database_principals roles ON memberof.role_principal_id = roles.principal_id and roles.type = 'R' where users.name = '[{0}]'", currentUserName);
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

        conn.Open();
        CurrentUser currentUser = new CurrentUser();
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (rdr.Read()) {
            currentUser.Role = rdr["Role"].ToString();
            currentUser.Username = currentUserName;
            rdr.Close();
        }
        conn.Close();

       return currentUser;

    }


public class CurrentUser
{
    public string Username {get;set;}
    public string Role {get;set;}
 }
```

in controller :

```
public IActionResult Index() {
        UsersDal dal = new UsersDal();
        ViewData["CurrentUser"] = dal.GetCurrentUser("username");

        return View();
    }
```

in cshtml:

```
@{
   var user = ViewData["CurrentUser"];
 }

 <b>@user.Username</b>
```

Comment: Could you please further explain your comment `After ViewData["CurrentUser"] = new method and controller pass.`

Comment: ViewData["CurrentUser"] =GetCurrentUser("hakan");

Comment: First of all create instance UsersDAL.After:

 instance.GetCurrentUser("hakan")

Comment: I mean how do I pass the current logged in username from the controller to the DAL function and get the result back to the controller in ViewData

Comment: You can use this >>> var currentUser = ViewData["CurrentUser"];  @currentUser.Username in View(cshtml)

Comment: Could you please update it in your answer? Also, what I would like to fetch in the view is the current user role.

Comment: I want to have the role returned for the current user. But your answer seems to be returning username

Comment: `<b>@user.Username</b>` or `<b>@user.Role</b>` gives the following error in the view `object does not contain a defination  of Username`